# Поэтому(,) прежде чем

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в скобках?

Поэтому(,) прежде чем давать секретарю поручение об уничтожении документов, нужно удостовериться, что их сроки хранения истекли.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая необходима, так как встречаются простой и составной союз. Запятая может либо стоять перед составным союзом (*Поэтому, прежде чем давать*), либо делить его на части (*Поэтому прежде, чем давать*). Но чаще составной подчинительный союз *прежде чем* целиком входит в придаточную часть.

Comment: А поэтому - это союз?

Comment: Примеры из словарей и учебников фиксируют союз "поэтому" между частями предложения. Но союз может соединять и предложения, тем более парцеллированные. Что происходит с "поэтому" при парцелляции: он меняет значение "вследствие этого" на "по этой причине"? Если "поэтому" союз между частями предложения, то он союз и в начале предложения.

Comment: Я к тому, что в словарях указывается, что  ПОЭТОМУ - это наречие, но не союз. А в грамматических учебниках он фигурирует исключительно в роли коррелята. У вас не найдется ссылки на текст, где ПОЭТОМУ назван союзом и определен его вид. Кстати, парцелляция — конструкция экспрессивного синтаксиса, представляющая собой намеренное расчленение связанного интонационно и на письме текста на несколько пунктуационно самостоятельных отрезков. Кажется, в деловой переписке парцелляцию не стоило бы употреблять.У вас не найдется ссылки на текст, где дается другое (расширенное) определение парцелляции?

Comment: Здесь была дискуссия на тему "Союз или наречие?": http://www.gramota.ru/forum/spravka/63517/ Для меня показателен "Словарь наречий и служебных слов рус. яз.". Я неточно выразилась: не союз, а союзное слово. 1. Наречие (по этой причине, вот почему): Ты на меня из-за соседки обиделась? - Да, поэтому. 2. Союзное слово (вследствие этого, потому; присоединяет придаточное со значением причины): Холодно стало, поэтому нагреватель включили.

Comment: Меня интересуют случаи, когда "поэтому" в начале предложения. В справочниках ни одного примера. Когда конструкции, присоединяемые к основному высказыванию союзами, парцеллируются, парцелляция совпадает с присоединением: http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lingvistic/1233/присоединительные И здесь: http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lingvistic/1057/парцелляция Когда придаточное отделяется, "поэтому" оказывается в начале предложения. Ни значение, ни функция не меняются. Но в справочниках о таких случаях ничего не сказано. Как-то странно это.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки. При возможности попробую сравнить материал с новыми вузовскими учебниками. Ну вот в самом новом (2014 год) есть материал о наречии ПОЭТОМУ. Сравниваются СПП и БСП. "Дождь кончился, поэтому можно идти гулять". Это БСП, так как его можно разделить на два простых предложения, ПОЭТОМУ -  наречие. "Не знаю, когда кончился дождь".  Разделить на два предложения нельзя, КОГДА - союзное слово. Может быть, найдется что-нибудь еще по теме.

Answer (score 5):

При просмотре Нацкорпуса можно видеть, что встречаются три варианта решения:

1) Поэтому, прежде чем писать письмо, Карташев решил привести себя в равновесие (основной вариант).

2) Поэтому прежде, чем войти в Царствие Божие, нужно душу свою наполнить светом.

3) Поэтому прежде чем изменить орбиту астероида, его параметры надо очень точно измерить.

Все три варианта могут иметь семантическое, грамматическое и интонационное обоснование.

Вариант 1. Наречие входит в состав главного предложения, на него падает тоническое ударение, автору важно подчеркнуть причинно-следственные отношения, которые выражает наречие "поэтому".

Вариант 2. Наречие относится к союзу "прежде чем", вследствие чего он расчленяется запятой. Тоническое ударение падает на слово "прежде", при этом подчеркивается временная последовательность событий.

Вариант 3. Наречие относится к союзу "прежде чем", но он не расчленяется, что характерно для его положения в начале предложения. Главная и придаточная части интонационно и семантически не выделяются.

РЕШЕНИЕ

Предлагается использовать вариант (3) без запятой, который лучше подходит для делового стиля  предложения: "Поэтому прежде чем давать секретарю поручение об уничтожении документов, нужно удостовериться, что их сроки хранения истекли".

Comment: Разъясните, пожалуйста, третий вариант. "Поэтому" относится к главному предложению, придаточное можно переставить, — нет мотивации не ставить запятую.

Answer (score 1):

Да, запятая нужна. См.здесь: http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_628

Comment: Я думаю, автор вопроса имел в виду, на том ли месте стоит запятая. Не надо ли ее поставить после слова прежде... Ваши комментарии, Серж.

Comment: Ссылка не работает,

Comment: @Аеr, ссылка рабочая. Просто ответ, который можно было найти, пройдясь по ссылке, уже удален.