# Запятая после ПОЭТОМУ

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, ставится ли запятая после слова *поэтому*?

Comment: Смотрите ответы  в поисковике. Повтор вопроса, который неоднократно имел ответ. Например здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/34851/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC

Answer (score 4):

Только в тех случаях, когда следующая за этим словом конструкция требует обособления или отделения запятой:

> Поэтому, если нет особых на то причин, запятую ставить не нужно.
>
> Именно поэтому, а не по какой-то другой причине.
>
> Поэтому сначала нужно всё проанализировать.

Answer (score 0):

Если "поэтому" является поясняемым обстоятельством причины в первой части бессоюзного сложного предложения, то после этого слова ставится двоеточие, например:

> Я доверяю любящим именно поэтому: они великодушны.

Если же данное слово имеется во второй части БСП —то перед ним (!)   ставится запятая:

> Любящие великодушны, поэтому я им доверяю.